# How is this process defined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{{a_1}{b_1}+{a_2}{b_2}}{{a_1}+{a_2}} = \text{ ?}$$

What is this called? It finds the value of b that corresponds to the average value of a. For some reason I just can't see the intuition behind it.

Also, can someone explain the more general terms for what this is called? In physics, a mass is also described by its position so it has two components. Can this be generalized to many 'components' like $$\frac{{a_1}{b_1}{c_1}+{a_2}{b_2}{c_2}}{{a_1}{b_1}+{a_2}{b_2}}$$ to find the c value that corresponds to the average values of a and b?

Comment: Your first expression looks like a weighted average of $b_1,b_2$ with weights $a_1,a_2$.

Comment: wow thanks http://puu.sh/nLaaO/f6b6fc757e.png lol I found it. :) you should answer so i can accept it.

Comment: @Obliv, in spite of waiting for acceptance of an answer, this question should be deleted. This may receive more down-votes(though I am not the downvoter).

Comment: why is that? It is general enough to be of significance to any further readers. Does it violate any rules that I don't know about? I looked for the mathematical term to this trivial process and could not find it. I have gaps in my math knowledge and it's annoying to see that when I'm studying physics. In my eyes, this is completely valid. Whether it gets upvotes or downvotes is irrelevant to me.

Comment: I agree that it is valid.  Some people think that if it is not clear to _them_ what's being asked, then it's unclear what is being asked.  That's probably the reason for the one down-vote that's happened so far and the vote to close. I think generally those who down-vote questions or vote to close questions move to fast in so doing. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weighted average of $b_1$ and $b_2$ with weights proportional to $a_1$ and $a_2$.  In all weighted averages, the weights must be non-negative and add up to $1$, so "weights proportional to $a_1$ and $a_2$" means the weights are $ca_1$ and $ca_2$, for some positive number $c$.  The number $c$ must satisfy the equation $ca_1+ca_2=1$.  That means $c = 1 / (a_1+a_2)$, so the weights are
$$
\frac{a_1}{a_1+a_2} \text{ and } \frac{a_2}{a_1+a_2}.
$$